# Android Proguard skip external jar

Tags: android, jar, external, proguard

I tried to use Proguard in my Android project, i setup Proguard using command line 'android update project /path/to/project' and file proguard.cfg was created in project's root directory. (In my Eclipse with Android 2.3 sdk, when create a new project, proguard.cfg file is not automatically created so i have to add it manually using command line).

When i export the project, i got the following errors

```
    [2011-02-06 09:02:49 - TestProject] Warning: oauth.signpost.jetty.HttpRequestAdapter: can't find referenced class org.mortbay.jetty.client.HttpExchange
[2011-02-06 09:02:49 - TestProject] Warning: oauth.signpost.jetty.HttpRequestAdapter: can't find referenced class org.mortbay.jetty.HttpFields
[2011-02-06 09:02:49 - TestProject] Warning: oauth.signpost.jetty.HttpRequestAdapter: can't find referenced class org.mortbay.jetty.client.HttpExchange
[2011-02-06 09:02:49 - TestProject] Warning: oauth.signpost.jetty.HttpRequestAdapter: can't find referenced class org.mortbay.io.Buffer
[2011-02-06 09:02:49 - TestProject] Warning: oauth.signpost.jetty.HttpRequestAdapter: can't find referenced class org.mortbay.jetty.client.HttpExchange
[2011-02-06 09:02:49 - TestProject] Warning: oauth.signpost.jetty.HttpRequestAdapter: can't find referenced class org.mortbay.jetty.client.HttpExchange
[2011-02-06 09:02:49 - TestProject] Warning: oauth.signpost.jetty.HttpRequestAdapter: can't find referenced class org.mortbay.jetty.HttpFields
[2011-02-06 09:02:49 - TestProject] Warning: oauth.signpost.jetty.HttpRequestAdapter: can't find referenced class org.mortbay.jetty.HttpFields$Field
[2011-02-06 09:02:49 - TestProject] Warning: oauth.signpost.jetty.HttpRequestAdapter: can't find referenced class org.mortbay.jetty.HttpFields$Field
[2011-02-06 09:02:49 - TestProject] Warning: oauth.signpost.jetty.HttpRequestAdapter: can't find referenced class org.mortbay.jetty.HttpFields$Field
[2011-02-06 09:02:49 - TestProject] Warning: oauth.signpost.jetty.HttpRequestAdapter: can't find referenced class org.mortbay.jetty.client.HttpExchange
[2011-02-06 09:02:49 - TestProject] Warning: oauth.signpost.jetty.HttpRequestAdapter: can't find referenced class org.mortbay.jetty.client.HttpExchange
[2011-02-06 09:02:49 - TestProject] Warning: oauth.signpost.jetty.HttpRequestAdapter: can't find referenced class org.mortbay.jetty.client.Address
[2011-02-06 09:02:49 - TestProject] Warning: oauth.signpost.jetty.HttpRequestAdapter: can't find referenced class org.mortbay.jetty.client.HttpExchange
[2011-02-06 09:02:49 - TestProject] Warning: oauth.signpost.jetty.HttpRequestAdapter: can't find referenced class org.mortbay.jetty.client.HttpExchange
[2011-02-06 09:02:49 - TestProject] Warning: oauth.signpost.jetty.HttpRequestAdapter: can't find referenced class org.mortbay.jetty.HttpFields
[2011-02-06 09:02:49 - TestProject] Warning: oauth.signpost.jetty.HttpRequestAdapter: can't find referenced class org.mortbay.io.Buffer
[2011-02-06 09:02:49 - TestProject] Warning: oauth.signpost.jetty.HttpRequestAdapter: can't find referenced class org.mortbay.jetty.client.Address
[2011-02-06 09:02:49 - TestProject] Warning: oauth.signpost.jetty.HttpRequestAdapter: can't find referenced class org.mortbay.jetty.client.HttpExchange
[2011-02-06 09:02:49 - TestProject] Warning: oauth.signpost.jetty.HttpRequestAdapter: can't find referenced class org.mortbay.jetty.client.HttpExchange
[2011-02-06 09:02:49 - TestProject] Warning: oauth.signpost.jetty.HttpRequestAdapter: can't find referenced class org.mortbay.jetty.client.HttpExchange
[2011-02-06 09:02:49 - TestProject] Warning: oauth.signpost.jetty.HttpRequestAdapter: can't find referenced class org.mortbay.jetty.HttpFields
[2011-02-06 09:02:49 - TestProject] Warning: oauth.signpost.jetty.HttpRequestAdapter: can't find referenced class org.mortbay.jetty.HttpFields
[2011-02-06 09:02:49 - TestProject] Warning: oauth.signpost.jetty.HttpRequestAdapter: can't find referenced class org.mortbay.jetty.HttpFields$Field
[2011-02-06 09:02:49 - TestProject] Warning: oauth.signpost.jetty.HttpRequestAdapter: can't find referenced class org.mortbay.jetty.HttpFields
[2011-02-06 09:02:49 - TestProject] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.CommonsLoggingLoggerFactory: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2011-02-06 09:02:49 - TestProject] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.CommonsLoggingLoggerFactory: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2011-02-06 09:02:49 - TestProject] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.SLF4JLoggerFactory: can't find referenced class org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
[2011-02-06 09:02:49 - TestProject] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.SLF4JLoggerFactory: can't find referenced class org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
[2011-02-06 09:02:49 - TestProject] Warning: oauth.signpost.jetty.JettyOAuthConsumer: can't find referenced class org.mortbay.jetty.client.HttpExchange
[2011-02-06 09:02:49 - TestProject] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.Log4JLoggerFactory: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Logger
[2011-02-06 09:02:49 - TestProject] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.Log4JLoggerFactory: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Logger
[2011-02-06 09:02:49 - TestProject] Warning: oauth.signpost.signature.OAuthMessageSigner: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64
[2011-02-06 09:02:49 - TestProject] Warning: oauth.signpost.signature.OAuthMessageSigner: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64
[2011-02-06 09:02:49 - TestProject] Warning: oauth.signpost.signature.OAuthMessageSigner: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64
[2011-02-06 09:02:49 - TestProject] Warning: oauth.signpost.signature.OAuthMessageSigner: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64
[2011-02-06 09:02:49 - TestProject] Warning: oauth.signpost.signature.OAuthMessageSigner: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64
[2011-02-06 09:02:49 - TestProject] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.SLF4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.slf4j.Logger
[2011-02-06 09:02:49 - TestProject] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.SLF4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.slf4j.Logger
[2011-02-06 09:02:49 - TestProject] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.SLF4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.slf4j.Logger
[2011-02-06 09:02:49 - TestProject] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.SLF4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.slf4j.Logger
[2011-02-06 09:02:49 - TestProject] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.SLF4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.slf4j.Logger
[2011-02-06 09:02:49 - TestProject] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.SLF4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.slf4j.Logger
[2011-02-06 09:02:49 - TestProject] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.SLF4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.slf4j.Logger
[2011-02-06 09:02:49 - TestProject] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.SLF4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.slf4j.Logger
[2011-02-06 09:02:49 - TestProject] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.SLF4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.slf4j.Logger
[2011-02-06 09:02:49 - TestProject] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.SLF4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.slf4j.Logger
[2011-02-06 09:02:49 - TestProject] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Logger
[2011-02-06 09:02:49 - TestProject] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Logger
[2011-02-06 09:02:49 - TestProject] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Level
[2011-02-06 09:02:49 - TestProject] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Logger
[2011-02-06 09:02:49 - TestProject] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Logger
[2011-02-06 09:02:49 - TestProject] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Logger
[2011-02-06 09:02:49 - TestProject] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Logger
[2011-02-06 09:02:49 - TestProject] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Logger
[2011-02-06 09:02:49 - TestProject] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Level
[2011-02-06 09:02:49 - TestProject] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Logger
[2011-02-06 09:02:49 - TestProject] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Logger
[2011-02-06 09:02:49 - TestProject] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Logger
[2011-02-06 09:02:49 - TestProject]       You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
[2011-02-06 09:02:49 - TestProject] Warning: there were 59 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
[2011-02-06 09:02:49 - TestProject]          You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars'),
[2011-02-06 09:02:49 - TestProject]          or perhaps the '-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses' option.
[2011-02-06 09:02:49 - TestProject] java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
[2011-02-06 09:02:49 - TestProject]     at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:308)
[2011-02-06 09:02:49 - TestProject]     at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:210)
[2011-02-06 09:02:49 - TestProject]     at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:85)
[2011-02-06 09:02:49 - TestProject]     at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:499)
```

These error messages point to four external jars used in my project

(.classpath)

```
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="/Users/lorensiuswlt/Android/android-sdk-mac_x86/libs/Twitter/signpost-commonshttp4-1.2.1.1.jar"/>
        <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/Users/lorensiuswlt/Android/android-sdk-mac_x86/libs/Twitter/signpost-core-1.2.1.1.jar"/>
        <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/Users/lorensiuswlt/Android/android-sdk-mac_x86/libs/Twitter/signpost-jetty6-1.2.1.1.jar"/>
        <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/Users/lorensiuswlt/Android/android-sdk-mac_x86/libs/Twitter/twitter4j-core-2.1.6.jar"/>
```

Here is my proguard.cfg file

```
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontpreverify
-verbose
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}
```

I've tried some solutions found on web by adding '-libraryjars' option, ex:

```
-libraryjars /Users/lorensiuswlt/Android/android-sdk-mac_x86/libs/Twitter/twitter4j-core-2.1.6.jar
```

but it won't help.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Your library jars refer to yet more library jars (Mortbay, SLF4J, Apache Commons Logging, Log4j, ...) Adding these jars with extra '-libraryjars' options should solve the problem.

If you are absolutely sure that your code doesn't use these libraries, you can specify '-ignorewarnings' or '-dontwarn', e.g.

```
-dontwarn org.mortbay.**
-dontwarn org.slf4j.**
-dontwarn org.apache.log4j.**
-dontwarn org.apache.commons.logging.**
-dontwarn org.apache.commons.codec.binary.**
```

Comment: Hi Eric, thanx for the solution. I've added -libraryjars to library you've pointed out:  the warning messages dissappear but when i run the app force closed, from the log messages i found 'classnotfound exception' on twitter4j

Comment: try adding the class which caused the "ClassNotFoundException" to the "keep" options `-keep public class com.example.Foo { public protected *; }`

Comment: what path would you use in the -libraryjars option?  I can't seem to figure that out.

Comment: @littleFluffyKitty The path to the library jar, as shown in the original question, for all library jars that are needed. You can find the ProGuard manual online, with many examples.

Comment: I have the same problem here. with @EricLafortune 's solution, I will have hundreds of classes need to -dontwarn (even I use regex like abc.xxx.**). Is there any other approach for this (aside from -libraryjars and -dontwarn)?

Comment: @LorensiusW.L.T did this answer actually solved your problem? I'm having a similar situation but it doesn't work for me.. If it didn't help did anything else do? Thanks!