# Proguard errors with external jar - returns error code 1

Tags: android, proguard

While exporting my Android Application, Proguard returned with error code 1. I am using twitter4j external jars in my app.

I already added library jars, rt.jar (For this I downloaded latest jdk1.7 which has javax.management.* classes) and dontwarn statements also to proguard.cfg file.

I included injars, libraryjars statements also..

**Updated**

```
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers
-dontpreverify
-dontshrink
-verbose

#-injars bin/classes
#-injars libs
#-outjars bin/classes-processed.jar

-libraryjars <java.home>/jre/lib/rt.jar
-libraryjars <java.home>/lib/tools.jar
-libraryjars /libs/twitter4j-core-3.0.3.jar
-libraryjars /libs/twitter4j-media-support-3.0.3.jar
-libraryjars /libs/linkedin-j-android.jar
-libraryjars /libs/signpost-commonshttp4-1.2.jar
-libraryjars /libs/signpost-core-1.2.1.1.jar
-libraryjars /libs/signpost-jetty6-1.2.1.1.jar

-dontwarn org.apache.**
-dontwarn org.slf4j.**
-dontwarn org.json.*
-dontwarn org.mortbay.**
-dontwarn org.apache.log4j.**
-dontwarn org.apache.commons.logging.**
-dontwarn org.apache.commons.logging.**
-dontwarn org.apache.commons.codec.binary.**
-dontwarn javax.xml.**
-dontwarn javax.management.**
-dontwarn java.lang.management.**
-dontwarn android.support.**
-dontwarn com.google.code.**
-dontwarn oauth.signpost.**
-dontwarn twitter4j.**

-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

-keep class javax.**  { *; }
-keep class org.**  { *; }
-keep class twitter4j.**  { *; }
-keep class java.lang.management.**  { *; }
-keep class com.google.code.**  { *; }
-keep class oauth.signpost.**  { *; }

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}
```

Still I am facing the issue, Proguard returned with error code 1.

**Updated**
LogCat:

```
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: com.google.code.linkedinapi.schema.Adapter1: can't find superclass or interface javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: com.google.code.linkedinapi.schema.Adapter2: can't find superclass or interface javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find superclass or interface javax.management.DynamicMBean
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: com.google.code.linkedinapi.schema.Adapter1: can't find referenced class javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: com.google.code.linkedinapi.schema.Adapter1: can't find referenced class javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: com.google.code.linkedinapi.schema.Adapter1: can't find referenced class javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: com.google.code.linkedinapi.schema.Adapter2: can't find referenced class javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: com.google.code.linkedinapi.schema.Adapter2: can't find referenced class javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: com.google.code.linkedinapi.schema.Adapter2: can't find referenced class javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: com.google.code.linkedinapi.schema.Adapter2: can't find referenced class javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: com.google.code.linkedinapi.schema.Adapter2: can't find referenced class javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: com.google.code.linkedinapi.schema.Adapter2: can't find referenced class javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: oauth.signpost.commonshttp.CommonsHttpOAuthProvider: can't find referenced method 'java.util.Map decodeForm(java.io.InputStream)' in class oauth.signpost.OAuth
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: oauth.signpost.commonshttp.CommonsHttpOAuthProvider: can't find referenced method 'void setResponseParameters(java.util.Map)' in class oauth.signpost.commonshttp.CommonsHttpOAuthProvider
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: oauth.signpost.jetty.HttpRequestAdapter: can't find referenced class org.mortbay.jetty.client.HttpExchange
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: oauth.signpost.jetty.HttpRequestAdapter: can't find referenced class org.mortbay.jetty.HttpFields
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: oauth.signpost.jetty.HttpRequestAdapter: can't find referenced class org.mortbay.jetty.client.HttpExchange
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: oauth.signpost.jetty.HttpRequestAdapter: can't find referenced class org.mortbay.io.Buffer
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: oauth.signpost.jetty.HttpRequestAdapter: can't find referenced class org.mortbay.jetty.client.HttpExchange
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: oauth.signpost.jetty.HttpRequestAdapter: can't find referenced class org.mortbay.jetty.client.HttpExchange
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: oauth.signpost.jetty.HttpRequestAdapter: can't find referenced class org.mortbay.jetty.HttpFields
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: oauth.signpost.jetty.HttpRequestAdapter: can't find referenced class org.mortbay.jetty.HttpFields$Field
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: oauth.signpost.jetty.HttpRequestAdapter: can't find referenced class org.mortbay.jetty.HttpFields$Field
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: oauth.signpost.jetty.HttpRequestAdapter: can't find referenced class org.mortbay.jetty.HttpFields$Field
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: oauth.signpost.jetty.HttpRequestAdapter: can't find referenced class org.mortbay.jetty.client.HttpExchange
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: oauth.signpost.jetty.HttpRequestAdapter: can't find referenced class org.mortbay.jetty.client.HttpExchange
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: oauth.signpost.jetty.HttpRequestAdapter: can't find referenced class org.mortbay.jetty.client.Address
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: oauth.signpost.jetty.HttpRequestAdapter: can't find referenced class org.mortbay.jetty.client.HttpExchange
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: oauth.signpost.jetty.HttpRequestAdapter: can't find referenced class org.mortbay.jetty.client.HttpExchange
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: oauth.signpost.jetty.HttpRequestAdapter: can't find referenced class org.mortbay.jetty.HttpFields
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: oauth.signpost.jetty.HttpRequestAdapter: can't find referenced class org.mortbay.io.Buffer
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: oauth.signpost.jetty.HttpRequestAdapter: can't find referenced class org.mortbay.jetty.client.Address
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: oauth.signpost.jetty.HttpRequestAdapter: can't find referenced class org.mortbay.jetty.client.HttpExchange
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: oauth.signpost.jetty.HttpRequestAdapter: can't find referenced class org.mortbay.jetty.client.HttpExchange
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: oauth.signpost.jetty.HttpRequestAdapter: can't find referenced class org.mortbay.jetty.client.HttpExchange
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: oauth.signpost.jetty.HttpRequestAdapter: can't find referenced class org.mortbay.jetty.HttpFields
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: oauth.signpost.jetty.HttpRequestAdapter: can't find referenced class org.mortbay.jetty.HttpFields
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: oauth.signpost.jetty.HttpRequestAdapter: can't find referenced class org.mortbay.jetty.HttpFields$Field
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: oauth.signpost.jetty.HttpRequestAdapter: can't find referenced class org.mortbay.jetty.HttpFields
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: oauth.signpost.jetty.JettyOAuthConsumer: can't find referenced class org.mortbay.jetty.client.HttpExchange
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: oauth.signpost.signature.OAuthMessageSigner: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: oauth.signpost.signature.OAuthMessageSigner: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: oauth.signpost.signature.OAuthMessageSigner: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: oauth.signpost.signature.OAuthMessageSigner: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: oauth.signpost.signature.OAuthMessageSigner: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.TwitterAPIMonitor: can't find referenced class java.lang.management.ManagementFactory
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.TwitterAPIMonitor: can't find referenced class javax.management.ObjectName
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.TwitterAPIMonitor: can't find referenced class javax.management.ObjectName
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.TwitterAPIMonitor: can't find referenced class javax.management.MBeanServer
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.TwitterAPIMonitor: can't find referenced class javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.TwitterAPIMonitor: can't find referenced class javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.TwitterAPIMonitor: can't find referenced class javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.TwitterAPIMonitor: can't find referenced class javax.management.MBeanRegistrationException
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.TwitterAPIMonitor: can't find referenced class javax.management.MBeanRegistrationException
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.TwitterAPIMonitor: can't find referenced class javax.management.MBeanRegistrationException
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.TwitterAPIMonitor: can't find referenced class javax.management.NotCompliantMBeanException
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.TwitterAPIMonitor: can't find referenced class javax.management.NotCompliantMBeanException
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.TwitterAPIMonitor: can't find referenced class javax.management.NotCompliantMBeanException
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.TwitterAPIMonitor: can't find referenced class javax.management.MalformedObjectNameException
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.TwitterAPIMonitor: can't find referenced class javax.management.MalformedObjectNameException
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.TwitterAPIMonitor: can't find referenced class javax.management.MalformedObjectNameException
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.TwitterAPIMonitor: can't find referenced class java.lang.management.ManagementFactory
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.TwitterAPIMonitor: can't find referenced class javax.management.MBeanServer
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.TwitterAPIMonitor: can't find referenced class javax.management.ObjectName
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.TwitterAPIMonitor: can't find referenced class javax.management.ObjectName
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.TwitterAPIMonitor: can't find referenced class javax.management.MBeanServer
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.TwitterAPIMonitor: can't find referenced class javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.TwitterAPIMonitor: can't find referenced class javax.management.MBeanRegistrationException
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.TwitterAPIMonitor: can't find referenced class javax.management.NotCompliantMBeanException
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.TwitterAPIMonitor: can't find referenced class javax.management.MalformedObjectNameException
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.CommonsLoggingLoggerFactory: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.CommonsLoggingLoggerFactory: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Logger
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Logger
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Level
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Logger
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Logger
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Logger
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Logger
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Logger
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Logger
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Logger
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Level
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Logger
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Logger
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Logger
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.Log4JLoggerFactory: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Logger
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.Log4JLoggerFactory: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Logger
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.SLF4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.slf4j.Logger
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.SLF4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.slf4j.Logger
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.SLF4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.slf4j.Logger
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.SLF4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.slf4j.Logger
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.SLF4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.slf4j.Logger
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.SLF4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.slf4j.Logger
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.SLF4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.slf4j.Logger
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.SLF4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.slf4j.Logger
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.SLF4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.slf4j.Logger
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.SLF4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.slf4j.Logger
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.SLF4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.slf4j.Logger
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.SLF4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.slf4j.Logger
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.SLF4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.slf4j.Logger
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.SLF4JLoggerFactory: can't find referenced class org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.SLF4JLoggerFactory: can't find referenced class org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.CompositeType
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.CompositeType
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.TabularType
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.TabularType
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.OpenDataException
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.OpenMBeanAttributeInfoSupport
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.OpenMBeanConstructorInfoSupport
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.OpenMBeanOperationInfoSupport
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.MBeanNotificationInfo
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.SimpleType
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.OpenMBeanAttributeInfoSupport
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.OpenMBeanParameterInfoSupport
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.OpenMBeanConstructorInfoSupport
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.SimpleType
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.OpenMBeanOperationInfoSupport
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.OpenMBeanInfoSupport
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.OpenMBeanInfoSupport
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.TabularDataSupport
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.TabularDataSupport
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.CompositeDataSupport
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.CompositeDataSupport
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.TabularDataSupport
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.AttributeNotFoundException
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.AttributeNotFoundException
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.AttributeList
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.AttributeList
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.Attribute
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.Attribute
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.AttributeList
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.ReflectionException
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.ReflectionException
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.OpenType
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.SimpleType
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.DynamicMBean
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.MBeanException
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.InvalidAttributeValueException
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.SimpleType
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.OpenType
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.CompositeType
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.TabularType
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.OpenDataException
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.MBeanInfo
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.OpenMBeanInfoSupport
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.OpenMBeanAttributeInfoSupport
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.OpenMBeanConstructorInfoSupport
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.OpenMBeanOperationInfoSupport
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.MBeanNotificationInfo
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.OpenMBeanParameterInfo
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.TabularDataSupport
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.CompositeData
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.OpenDataException
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.TabularDataSupport
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.AttributeList
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.AttributeList
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.Attribute
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.Attribute
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.AttributeList
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.AttributeList
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.AttributeList
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP]       You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: there were 160 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP]          You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars').
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] Warning: there were 2 unresolved references to program class members.
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP]          Your input classes appear to be inconsistent.
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP]          You may need to recompile them and try again.
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP]          Alternatively, you may have to specify the option 
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP]          '-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers'.
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP] java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP]  at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:321)
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP]  at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:211)
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP]  at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:86)
[2013-02-18 10:43:47 - SP]  at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)
```

Comment: post the complete logcat message

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. You can see the completed logcat and proguard file from the following link.

http://host01.fileconvoy.com/dfl.php?id=g26cefda58204e8e7999206568eabbdef672f4e963

Comment: Is signpost in your buildpath ? i used to had these errors when i didn't have some jars in my buildpath. edit - same question for the other jars aswell

Comment: All my jars in /libs folder. So, I have not explicitly added those jars in to my build path. Also I tried by commenting dontwarn signpost jar lines in config file, still no success

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thank you so much for all. Finally after so much struggling I found my foolish mistake. I have configured wrong config file in project.properties.

I was changing code in proguard.cfg, but the project.properties file contains wrong config file path i.e.

```
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt
```

Fixed with this changes:

```
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard.cfg
```

**proguard.cfg working version**

```
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers
-dontpreverify
-dontshrink
-verbose

-injars bin/classes
-injars libs
-outjars bin/classes-processed.jar

-libraryjars C:/glassfish3/jdk7/jre/lib/rt.jar 
-libraryjars C:/glassfish3/jdk7/lib/tools.jar

-dontwarn org.apache.**
-dontwarn org.slf4j.**
-dontwarn org.json.*
-dontwarn org.mortbay.**
-dontwarn org.apache.log4j.**
-dontwarn org.apache.commons.logging.**
-dontwarn org.apache.commons.logging.**
-dontwarn org.apache.commons.codec.binary.**
-dontwarn javax.xml.**
-dontwarn javax.management.**
-dontwarn java.lang.management.**
-dontwarn android.support.**
-dontwarn com.google.code.**
-dontwarn oauth.signpost.**
-dontwarn twitter4j.**

-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
-keep public class com.google.code.linkedinapi.**

-keep class javax.**  { *; }
-keep class org.**  { *; }
-keep class twitter4j.**  { *; }
-keep class java.lang.management.**  { *; }
-keep class com.google.code.**  { *; }
-keep class oauth.signpost.**  { *; }

-keepclassmembers public class com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.impl.LinkedInApiXppClient {
     public <init>(java.lang.String, java.lang.String);
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}
```

Comment: I had to add -dontwarn com.google.ads.** for some reason  and then the answe worked.

Comment: Huge thanks dear for posting this helpful code snip.It helped me a lot cheers!!

Answer (score 16):

Try adding the Packages which give warnings, this way:

```
-dontwarn com.google.code.**
-dontwarn oauth.signpost.**
-dontwarn twitter4j.**
```

For some reason if this didn't work try doing the same with Class and Interface Names, this way:

```
-dontwarn javax.management.**
-dontwarn javax.xml.**
-dontwarn org.apache.**
-dontwarn org.slf4j.**
```

to your **Proguard config file**.

Comment: No success, still same errors showing in logcat. I also added following missed libraries with above dontwarn statemets.
    -libraryjars libs/linkedin-j-android.jar
    -libraryjars libs/signpost-commonshttp4-1.2.jar
    -libraryjars libs/signpost-core-1.2.1.1.jar
    -libraryjars libs/signpost-jetty6-1.2.1.1.jar

Comment: You got the same logcat? After adding these line atleast the number of warnings must be reduced. Please update the question with the latest config file

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick reply. 
Same number of warnings. Nothing has changed. I updated question with the latest proguard config file and logcat.

Comment: @Santhosh try the Edited answer. **Few classes which are part of JavaRunTime but not AndroidRunTime** give such warnings. In that case add the reference class to the `dontwarn` tag

Comment: I already added those dontwarn statements to my config file. Even though I tried again, still same errors no success.

Answer (score 3):

Given these `-dontwarn` options, you can't be getting these warnings from your build. You should double-check that you are editing the proper configuration file (`proguard-project.txt` as of Android SDK r20).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My issue has fixed few days back, what you said is correct. I did mistake in proguard configuration. Anyway giving upvote...

Answer (score 1):

I found a few things while integrating Proguard maybe it's helpful  to you.

1>While using Google's License Verification Library  we  want to keep an additional class from being obfuscated in the additional library. for that I used proguard/config.txt file:

```
**-keep class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService**
```

2>
While using Google api for MapActivity, I got warnings:

> can't find referenced classes for all come.google.android.maps
>   classes, and "Note: the configuration refers to the unknown class
>   'com.google.android.maps'"`

When we use Google APIs, there is an additional library used to build the program. for that we need to adjust the path.

Normally there is just android.jar located in your SDK. but Google API adds another library, maps.jar, hidden away at android-sdk-windows\add-ons\addon_google_apis_google_inc_8\libs\maps.jar. We need to add this to the build.xml file. Find the optimize target in build.xml, and add the following text in bold to the proguard command by adjusting the path:

```
<arg value="-libraryjars ${android.jar}"/>
<arg value="-libraryjars ${sdk.dir}/add-ons\addon_google_apis_google_inc_8\libs\maps.jar"/>
```

Have a look at this ref: http://goo.gl/Ifgyj

3> Ref: [Android Proguard skip external jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911129/android-proguard-skip-external-jar)

Comment: I have not used Google Maps, License and in-app purchase services in my application. Anyway that keep ... ILicensingService also added in my config file.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I have gone through the document and I think everything I added in my proguard config file with libraryjar but  no success.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the next line to your proguard file:

```
  -keep public class com.google.code.linkedinapi.**

  -keepclassmembers public class com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.impl.LinkedInApiXppClient {
     public <init>(java.lang.String, java.lang.String);
   }
```

---

And also add

```
-keep class twitter4j.**
-keepclassmembers class twitter4j.** {
    <init>(...);
    <methods>;
    <fields>;
}
```

and also a good idea to add

```
-keep public class * extends android.view.View {
    public <init>(android.content.Context);
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
    public void set*(...);
}
-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
    public static <fields>;
}
```

Comment: Tried with adding above statements also,  No success

Answer (score 0):

One thing that worked for me was to reduce the "optimizationpasses" try 2.

Comment: Tried with -optimizationpasses 2, No success

Answer (score 0):

I guess Android does not support jdk 1.7, May be that's your problem. [Can the Android SDK work with JDK 1.7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8578441/can-the-android-sdk-work-with-jdk-1-7)

Comment: I have updated my ADT to R21.1.0(http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html) and it takes Java 1.6 or higher. So, I changed my project compiler compliance level to 1.7. But its giving 'Android requires compiler compliance level 5.0 or 6.0. Found '1.7' instead'. I have checked everything its fine. Can u help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting a "Proguard returned with error code 1. See console" error. In my case the problem was in the "sdk\tools\proguard\bin\proguard.bat" file which the ADT uses to start ProGuard. It contained the line "java -jar "%PROGUARD_HOME%"\lib\proguard.jar %*". In my environment the simple command "java" doesn't work. I never use it because I specify specific JVMs in different circumstances.

Anyway, changing "java" to the absolute path of the JDK 1.7 bin\java.exe resolved the issue.