# Proguard lines for ActionBar 3.0 and above

Tags: android, android-actionbar, proguard

I have created the generalized application using the ActionBar with fragments for Android version 3.0 and above. I need use the Proguard for my application. I have tried the codes in the following link.

https://github.com/Decad3nce/Aegis/blob/master/proguard-project.txt

They specify the proguard lines of code for ActionBarSherlock. But I am using the ActionBar and Fragment for my application. How can I use the Progaurd for my application?

Comment: check the android example @ http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/examples.html

Comment: In the given link there no specification for Fragment and ActionBars.

Comment: using any external libraries? if not follow the steps in the link

Comment: I am using the library android.jar,android-support-v4.jar, annotations.jar, gson-2.2.1.jar. I am also want my application code as external library.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14501759/proguard-errors-with-external-jar-returns-error-code-1. might help

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have already seen this post. I need the lines to obfuscate the action bar codes and tab listerner fragments.

Comment: for each android project you need to configure proguard .It's not possible to give exact lines. I suggest you go through this link http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html#configuring

Comment: I am referring this link http://proguard.sourceforge.net/#manual/usage.html. I am having customization options in myproguard.pro. But I am unable to give the correct code to obfuscate the ActionBar and Fragments.