# Android - proguard error with twitter4j

Tags: proguard, twitter4j

I have a problem about exporting signed application package with external library of twitter4j.

Currently, I configured a proguard at eclipse as below.

Can you give me an advice ?

Let me know if you need any information.

Thanks

- Console : error message

  ```
  [ - ] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find superclass or interface javax.management.DynamicMBean
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.CommonsLoggingLoggerFactory: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.CommonsLoggingLoggerFactory: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Logger
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Logger
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Level
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Logger
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Logger
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Logger
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Logger
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Logger
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Logger
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Logger
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Level
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Logger
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Logger
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Logger
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.Log4JLoggerFactory: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Logger
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.Log4JLoggerFactory: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Logger
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.SLF4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.slf4j.Logger
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.SLF4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.slf4j.Logger
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.SLF4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.slf4j.Logger
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.SLF4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.slf4j.Logger
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.SLF4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.slf4j.Logger
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.SLF4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.slf4j.Logger
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.SLF4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.slf4j.Logger
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.SLF4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.slf4j.Logger
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.SLF4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.slf4j.Logger
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.SLF4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.slf4j.Logger
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.SLF4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.slf4j.Logger
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.SLF4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.slf4j.Logger
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.SLF4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.slf4j.Logger
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.SLF4JLoggerFactory: can't find referenced class org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.SLF4JLoggerFactory: can't find referenced class org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.TwitterAPIMonitor: can't find referenced class java.lang.management.ManagementFactory
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.TwitterAPIMonitor: can't find referenced class javax.management.ObjectName
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.TwitterAPIMonitor: can't find referenced class javax.management.ObjectName
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.TwitterAPIMonitor: can't find referenced class javax.management.MBeanServer
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.TwitterAPIMonitor: can't find referenced class javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.TwitterAPIMonitor: can't find referenced class javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.TwitterAPIMonitor: can't find referenced class javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.TwitterAPIMonitor: can't find referenced class javax.management.MBeanRegistrationException
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.TwitterAPIMonitor: can't find referenced class javax.management.MBeanRegistrationException
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.TwitterAPIMonitor: can't find referenced class javax.management.MBeanRegistrationException
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.TwitterAPIMonitor: can't find referenced class javax.management.NotCompliantMBeanException
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.TwitterAPIMonitor: can't find referenced class javax.management.NotCompliantMBeanException
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.TwitterAPIMonitor: can't find referenced class javax.management.NotCompliantMBeanException
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.TwitterAPIMonitor: can't find referenced class javax.management.MalformedObjectNameException
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.TwitterAPIMonitor: can't find referenced class javax.management.MalformedObjectNameException
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.TwitterAPIMonitor: can't find referenced class javax.management.MalformedObjectNameException
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.TwitterAPIMonitor: can't find referenced class javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.TwitterAPIMonitor: can't find referenced class javax.management.MBeanRegistrationException
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.TwitterAPIMonitor: can't find referenced class javax.management.NotCompliantMBeanException
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.TwitterAPIMonitor: can't find referenced class javax.management.MalformedObjectNameException
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.TwitterAPIMonitor: can't find referenced class java.lang.management.ManagementFactory
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.TwitterAPIMonitor: can't find referenced class javax.management.MBeanServer
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.TwitterAPIMonitor: can't find referenced class javax.management.MBeanServer
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.TwitterAPIMonitor: can't find referenced class javax.management.ObjectName
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.TwitterAPIMonitor: can't find referenced class javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.TwitterAPIMonitor: can't find referenced class javax.management.MBeanRegistrationException
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.TwitterAPIMonitor: can't find referenced class javax.management.NotCompliantMBeanException
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.TwitterAPIMonitor: can't find referenced class javax.management.MalformedObjectNameException
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.CompositeType
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.CompositeType
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.TabularType
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.TabularType
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.OpenDataException
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.OpenMBeanAttributeInfoSupport
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.OpenMBeanConstructorInfoSupport
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.OpenMBeanOperationInfoSupport
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.MBeanNotificationInfo
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.SimpleType
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.OpenMBeanAttributeInfoSupport
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.OpenMBeanParameterInfoSupport
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.OpenMBeanConstructorInfoSupport
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.SimpleType
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.MBeanOperationInfo
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.OpenMBeanOperationInfoSupport
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.OpenMBeanInfoSupport
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.OpenMBeanInfoSupport
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.TabularDataSupport
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.TabularDataSupport
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.CompositeDataSupport
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.CompositeDataSupport
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.TabularDataSupport
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.AttributeNotFoundException
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.AttributeNotFoundException
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.AttributeList
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.AttributeList
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.Attribute
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.Attribute
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.AttributeList
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.ReflectionException
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.ReflectionException
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.OpenType
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.SimpleType
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.DynamicMBean
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.OpenDataException
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.TabularDataSupport
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.MBeanException
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.AttributeList
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.InvalidAttributeValueException
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.SimpleType
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.OpenType
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.CompositeType
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.TabularType
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.OpenDataException
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.MBeanInfo
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.OpenMBeanInfoSupport
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.OpenMBeanAttributeInfoSupport
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.OpenMBeanConstructorInfoSupport
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.OpenMBeanOperationInfoSupport
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.MBeanNotificationInfo
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.OpenMBeanParameterInfo
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.TabularDataSupport
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.CompositeData
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.OpenDataException
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.TabularDataSupport
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.AttributeList
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.AttributeList
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.Attribute
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.Attribute
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.AttributeList
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.AttributeList
  [ - ] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.AttributeList
  [ - ]       You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
  [ - ] Warning: there were 125 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
  [ - ]          You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars').
  [ - ] java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
  [ - ]   at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:321)
  [ - ]   at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:211)
  [ - ]   at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:86)
  [ - ]   at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)
  ```
- file name : project.properties

  ```
  # This file is automatically generated by Android Tools.
  # Do not modify this file -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE ERASED!
  #
  # This file must be checked in Version Control Systems.
  #
  # To customize properties used by the Ant build system edit
  # "ant.properties", and override values to adapt the script to your
  # project structure.
  #
  # To enable ProGuard to shrink and obfuscate your code, uncomment this (available properties: sdk.dir, user.home):
  #proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt

  proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt

  # Project target.
  target=Google Inc.:Google APIs:19
  android.library.reference.1=../google-play-services_lib
  ```
- file name : proguard-android.txt in eclipse

  ```
  # To enable ProGuard in your project, edit project.properties
  # to define the proguard.config property as described in that file.
  #
  # Add project specific ProGuard rules here.
  # By default, the flags in this file are appended to flags specified
  # in ${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt
  # You can edit the include path and order by changing the ProGuard
  # include property in project.properties.
  #
  # For more details, see
  #   http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html

  # Add any project specific keep options here:

  # If your project uses WebView with JS, uncomment the following
  # and specify the fully qualified class name to the JavaScript interface
  # class:
  #-keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
  #   public *;
  #}
  ```

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14502915/2455484) solution. I had the same issue and it worked for me.