# Android apk Debug mode works fine but release mode gives too many warnings

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, proguard, release-mode

I'm trying to get a signed APK from eclipse. I have a debuggable apk version that works fine. Now for release when I tried to compile and sign with Eclipse ADT, I get many warnings, most of which is `can't find superclass or interface some.package.Class`. So, I referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4525661/android-proguard-cant-find-dynamically-referenced-class-javax-swing), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911129/android-proguard-skip-external-jar) and many others unfortunately I couldn't reach anywhere!

I also get `Note: there were 314 duplicate class definitions.` warning

My progaurd-project.txt was untouched earlier. So, I added `-libraryjars /libs/lib-name` for each of the jars present at `/EcliseProject/libs/` folder. So I came up with the following:

`-libraryjars /libs/android-support-v4.jar
-libraryjars /libs/apache-mime4j-core-0.7.2.jar
-libraryjars /libs/gcm.jar
-libraryjars /libs/httpclient-4.3.3.jar
-libraryjars /libs/httpcore-4.3.2.jar
-libraryjars /libs/httpmime-4.3.3.jar
-libraryjars /libs/library.jar
-libraryjars /libs/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar`

By the end of this I got some 1800+ warnings most of them being not finding superclass or interface as mentioned above. So, I got the jars that have those classes and put them too in /lib/ folder and added `-libraryjars` entries including `rt.jar`, etc. Then  I got even more warnings some of them saying `library class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser depends on program class java.lang.String`.

I tried adding `-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses`, adding some `-dontwarn`, etc. Nothing worked so far.

At some point I kept sufficient `-dontwarn`so that apk was made but it just brought up the login screen (1st activity) and once clicked on a button got stuck there.

I'm missing something very basic I guess.
All these days I was testing with debug mode apk which works normally. Why is this trouble? Please help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK after a lot of googling and searching within *stackoverflow* itself, I have manages to get a solution. The following is my `proguard-project.txt` file:

```
-libraryjars /libs/android-support-v4.jar
-libraryjars /libs/apache-mime4j-core-0.7.2.jar
-libraryjars /libs/gcm.jar
-libraryjars /libs/httpclient-4.3.3.jar
-libraryjars /libs/httpcore-4.3.2.jar
-libraryjars /libs/httpmime-4.3.3.jar
-libraryjars /libs/library.jar
-libraryjars /libs/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar

-keepnames class org.apache.** {*;}
-keep public class org.apache.** {*;}
-dontwarn org.apache.commons.**
-dontwarn org.apache.http.annotation.ThreadSafe
-dontwarn org.apache.http.annotation.Immutable
-dontwarn org.apache.http.annotation.NotThreadSafe
-dontwarn org.apache.http.impl.auth.GGSSchemeBase
-dontwarn org.apache.http.impl.auth.KerberosScheme
-dontwarn org.apache.http.impl.auth.NegotiateScheme
-dontwarn org.apache.http.impl.auth.KerberosScheme
-dontwarn org.apache.http.impl.auth.SPNegoScheme
-dontwarn se.emilsjolander.stickylistheaders.StickyListHeadersListView
-dontwarn android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient
```

Hope it helps others, Thanks!