# How to exclude java.bak files from release apk using proguard

Tags: java, android, eclipse, proguard, eclipse-adt

OK! I was stuck with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24415383/android-apk-debug-mode-works-fine-but-release-mode-gives-too-many-warnings) problem for quite a while and finally, with a lot of searching in stackoverflow and other places I somehow managed to fix that issue.

So, now I have a *release* mode apk ready but with a new problem. The apk contains all the *java.bak* files present inside eclipse.

I read about `_pre_production` but since `.bak` files don't have a separate location, that may not work (I think).

Is there a way to exclude `*.bak` files? Is there a configuration option within `proguard` to fix this? Or is it something else?